# How do I access the element which haven't been created yet in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, addeventlistener, event-listener

I am completeing the Etch-a-Sketch project of TheOdinProject. I want to access the grid's cell for changing it's color, but they are created in the scope of a `for()` loop and that `for()` loop is inside the scope of a function. I've searched other questions and not getting what I want or maybe I cannot understand whatis being conveyed.

The function for creating grid

```
function changeGridSize(number) {
  let container = document.getElementById(`container`);
  totalNumber = number * number;
  while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
    container.removeChild(container.firstChild);
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < totalNumber; i++) {
    let gridSquare = document.createElement("div");
    gridSquare.classList.add("grid_square");

    let cellwidth = container.clientWidth / number + `px`;
    let cellheight = container.clientHeight / number + `px`;

    gridSquare.setAttribute(
      `style`,
      `width: ${cellwidth}; height: ${cellheight};`
    );
    container.appendChild(gridSquare);
  }
}
```

The code for changing color

```
let color = document.getElementById(`colour_picker`);
color.addEventListener(`change`, changeColor() );
let choosenColour = color.value;

function changeColor() {
  while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
    gridSquare.setAttribute(`style`, `background-color: ${choosenColour};`)
  }
}
```

When the user picks a color from the color picker the background color for the cells should change to that color which the user selected.
But when I add the `change` event listener to the color picker the page is crashing and also when I try to change the grid size above 40x40.

Edit: html

````
    <div id="outer_container">
        <div id="container"> </div>
    </div>
    <div id="controls">
     <input type="color" class="user_input" name="" id="colour_picker" value="#000000">
    <div class="slider">
            <div class="toggle_change" id="arrow_down"></div>
            <input style="margin-bottom: 0;" class="user_input" type="range" min="2" max="100" value="16" name="options"
                id="grid_range">
            <div class="toggle_change" id="arrow_up"></div>
        </div>

    </div>
    </body>```
````

Comment: Simply, you can't. It will always throw you an `TypeError` or `RefeferenceError: Element is null`. YOu have either to fire a custom event or to re-reference the elements so that JS knows the element.

Comment: Maybe that color picker triggers custom event, so you can listen on that instead?

Comment: [Event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation) might help you.

Comment: First, `addEventListener(.... changeColor() );` doesn't look right, should be `..., changeColor)`. Next, in `changeColor` simply iterate `container.childNodes` and apply `setAttribute` to each child.

Comment: Translation of the first part of previous comment: Drop the `()` from `changeColor` in the event listener: `color.addEventListener('change', changeColor);` - there is also no need to use backticks everywhere. Only where you need to compose a string

Comment: also using `stlye` attribute is not needed when you can just use the prop `style` of an element.. by the way I made a working demo of your code.. I'm just not sure if you really meant to change the background color of each single `.grid_square` when the `change` event occurs on the color picker.

Comment: @mplungjan yess, this is what I did with everyone's help and it worked. Also thought it would be better if i only use backticks everywhere so in future I won't get confused in which inverted commas to use but now I'll start parcticing to only use them when needed.

Comment: We more or less standardised on Single Quotes `'string in script';` , Double Quotes `<tag "tag-attributes">` and backticks when you need `\`some ${template_literals}\``

Comment: @DiegoD yess right now what you did was exactly what I wanted, I'll try on my own to do the change in color when when the mouse is hovered over the `.grid_square`, might need some help if am not able to.

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks man will keep that in mind from now on.

Comment: Also note that if you plan to use JSON, then use double quotes for `{ "keys": "and string values", "but not numbers": 3 }`

Comment: @mplungjano Alright, will make sure abou that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's one main problem in your code, being how you pass the callback function to the `addEventListener` by invoking it instead of using its value.

Said that, I just simplified how you style the elements programmatically by using directly the `style` property of the element instead of changing the value of the `style` attribute.

I also decided to style the html that you didn't share according to my taste and most importatly setting the `#container` as a flexbox to accomodate the `n*n`squares inside.

```js
let container = document.getElementById(`container`);

//on page loaded, click the #resetGrid button
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
  document.getElementById('resetGrid').click();
})

//on click over the #resetGrid button, changeGridSize() accordingly
document.getElementById('resetGrid')
  .addEventListener('click', (event)=>{
    const size = document.getElementById('gridsize').value;
    changeGridSize(size);
  });

//empty the #container and add a number of div.grid_square based on arg number
function changeGridSize(number) {

  totalNumber = number * number;

  while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
    container.removeChild(container.firstChild);
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < totalNumber; i++) {
    let gridSquare = document.createElement("div");
    gridSquare.classList.add("grid_square");

    let cellwidth = container.clientWidth / number;
    let cellheight = container.clientHeight / number;

    gridSquare.style.width = `${cellwidth}px`;
    gridSquare.style.height = `${cellheight}px`;

    container.appendChild(gridSquare);
  }
}

let color = document.getElementById(`colour_picker`);
color.addEventListener(`change`, changeColor);

//called when #color_picker change event triggers,
//setting the background of each single .grid_square accordingly
function changeColor(event) {
  for (let box of container.children) {
    box.style.background = this.value;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;  
  padding-top:  3em;
}

#container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.grid_square {
  border: solid 1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*controls styles*/

.controls label[for="color_picker"]{
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
}

.controls .input-group {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.controls #gridsize{
  width: 2em;
  margin-right: .5em;
}

.controls button{
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <div class="controls">
    <label for="colour_picker">Pick a color:</label>
    <input id="colour_picker" type="color">
    <br><br>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input id="gridsize" type="number" value="4" style="width: 50px;">
      <button id="resetGrid">Reset</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. Also sorry I thought the post might become too big so I didn't included the html and css, I am actually using a slider to change the size of grid, and to 'up' and 'down' to increase or decrease it by one. 
So the `this.value` takes the value from the eventlisteners which was passed as the parameter right?